# email daily commit report for svn

Tags: xml, svn, tortoisesvn

I have a post commit hook that will save the svn log as an XML file.Next i have to do formatting for showing the data in the form of a tabular report that will have the following details:
1)Work Order NO
2)Filename
2)Filepath
3)Revision No.
4)Owner
5)Commit Time

This report needs to be send to a group everyday at 5 PM via email.
I need some sample code for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends upon the language you're using.

Many languages have modules for reading XML files. For example, Perl has the [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm) module.

If this is a daily report that you need for your Subversion repository at 5pm every day, you're better off simply running the report once at 5pm using some sort of scheduling software. On Unix systems, you could use the [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) daemon to schedule your system to run a script. On Windows, you can use the [Schedule Task Wizard](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569).

Running the report can be very simple. All you need is something like this:

```
svn log -v '{'$YESTERDAY'}':HEAD http://path/to/repository
```

You have to calculate what `$YESTERDAY` is and put it in `YYYYMMDD` format, and you have your report!

How do you get yesterday's date? Depends upon your programming language. Most operating systems store dates as the number of seconds from an *epoc* (In Unix, it's January 1, 1970). You use your programming language's date routines.

This would be listed in change set order with a list of of the files changed under each change set. If you need a different format, you could use the `--xml` switch, and get the report in XML format. The format for this XML output is pretty straight forward, and is so regular in structure that you could even parse it without using an XML parsing module.

I can't really give you much help beyond this. I don't know the OS, the language you use, or even exactly what you need in your report. All that I can tell you is that you don't need a post-commit hook -- just run the `svn log` at the appropriate time with the right parameters, and in minutes, you have your report all ready to mail out.

And, since this is using `svn`, all you need is the Subversion client. You don't even have to produce this report on a particular machine as long as that machine has a Subversion command line client (downloadable from many places) and someway to specify when the report can be run.

Comment: Thanks,I have generated thesvnlog.xml and have formatted it through XSLT stylesheet.But i am confused about how to send the XLST through mail.Do i need to write an aspx page for doing this or i can simply do it through HTML mail?

Comment: @user972889: You could display it as a webpage on your website and email the link to people. My understanding is that you can use XSLT to covert XML to HTML. Then, you'll should be able to mail the HTML. You still haven't mentioned what you're using for scripting, but in Perl, you can use [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MIME-Lite/lib/MIME/Lite.pm) to send your generated HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any reason to use a post-commit hook, because you can just get the data using `svn log -v --xml`. You can ask it for revisions by date; e.g., `svn log -v --xml -r "$(date +'{%Y-%m-%d}'):HEAD"` to get today's revisions. Remember also that svn log can be givin a URL instead of a local checkout.

Whatever programming language you're familiar with surely has XML parsing libraries you can use to transform the XML into your report.

You then just need to arrange for your program to be called once per day. On Unix, you'd use cron. On Windows, you can use the Task Scheduler.

Other than that, you're asking for something dangerously close to "write my code for me".

Answer (score 1):

I think that an SVN hook is the wrong task for this job.  After all this fires only after every commit (what if you have hundreds of commits a day?  what if no one is committing around 5pm?).  Instead, I would write a cron job (linux) or scheduled task (windows) to do this everyday at 5pm.  You can use the [svn command line tools to query the log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.tour.history.html) from the repository, reformat it and then email it.